# Windows 10 not showing time set in BIOS

Tags: windows, bios, time

I've been stuck on a problem for about a week now where I try to disable Windows 10 from synchronizing the time with any servers and have the OS reflect a time that I've changed it to in BIOS.

Steps that I've tried:

- `sc config W32Time start= disabled`
- `net stop W32Time`
- Changing time in BIOS and rebooting
- Removed wireless and ethernet
- Changed CMOS battery
- Reset CMOS

The OS still shows a time that is different than what I set to in BIOS.

Are there any tricks via registries or other services that I should know about?

Comment: I presume you have tried clicking on the clock and disabled it there?

Comment: Note that most PC's keep track of *two* clocks, so that you may need to set the Windows clock as well as the BIOS one.

Comment: @SDsolar, yes that's something I've attempted but forgot to mention.

Comment: what is the difference in the time you expect and the time you see?

Comment: @Keltari I'm changing it to 06/01/2017 12am in BIOS but don't see the changes reflected in the OS.  I've noticed that when I change the time in the OS, it will be reflected in BIOS, but not the other way around.  The BIOS time stays as expected when I reboot from BIOS to BIOS menu.  But loses the changes from BIOS to OS